# How can I compress the output of "tail -f" into a compressed (gzipped) file?

Tags: linux, compression, gzip, pipe, tail

I have tried the following, but the resulting file stays at size 0.

```
tail -f /logs/localhost.log | gzip -c -9 -f > compressed.gz
```

localhost.log is very active.

Thank you.

Comment: gzip does a lot of buffering.  It can take more than 1000 lines before anything arrives at tho output.  Maybe it's not *that* active?

Comment: Why not `gzip -c -9 -f < /log/localhost.log > /log/compressed.gz` ?

Answer (score 1):

[logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)(8) was designed to solve this sort of problem - it rotates and compresses log files.

Answer (score 1):

You're just not patient enough.  That will work, and it will write to the gzip file.  It will take a while to accumulate enough input to write the first compressed block.  Especially if the input is highly compressible, e.g. the log entries are very similar to each other.

This has a problem though, in that the gzip file will never be properly terminated, since gzip will never get an end-of-file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, because gzip utility doesn't read input line by line, it expects EOF.
But you can write your on wrapper using any programming language which has zlib implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure that `gzip` reads line by line (but it certainly has some buffer), and I am not sure it won't work before EOF (actually, when using `gzip` in a pipe after `tar` and `tardy` it is starting to work before EOF).